# In a Flutter widget test, how can I verify a field validation error message?

Tags: validation, flutter, flutter-test

I'm writing a widget test for a Flutter form, and want to verify that after form submission, validation fails, and `errorText` for one of the fields is displayed and is as expected.

The code for the field looks like:

```
Form(key: _formKey, ...
  TextFormField(validator: validateEmail, ...)
```

For the test assertion, I've tried things like

```
expect(find.text('Please fill in your email.'), findsOneWidget);
```

With no success. Hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 18):

I recreated your case and was able to validate the inline error message. The idea is to add a delay of 1 second before we could test assertion. Here's what I did:

`main.dart` code to display `textformfield` and validate Email upon tapping `Send` button:

```
TextFormField(
            decoration: new InputDecoration(hintText: 'Email ID'),
            keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
            maxLength: 32,
            validator: validateEmail,
            onSaved: (String val) {
              email = val;
            }),
```

`validateEmail` method snippet:

```
if (value.length == 0) {
      return "Email is Required";
    } else if(!regExp.hasMatch(value)){
      return "Invalid Email";
    }else {
      return null;
    }
```

Widget test to validate the inline error message for email field:

```
void main() {
  testWidgets('validate email inline error message',
          (WidgetTester tester) async {

        await tester.pumpWidget(MyApp());

        final buttonFinder = find.text('Send');
        final emailErrorFinder = find.text('Email is Required');

        await tester.tap(buttonFinder);
        print('button tapped');
        await tester.pump(const Duration(milliseconds: 100)); // add delay
            expect(emailErrorFinder, findsOneWidget);
        print('validated email inline error');
      });
}
```

Test result:

[image]

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for having a look, unfortunately this didn't do the trick in my case. However, I found that if, before I hit the button, I did a `tester.pumpAndSettle()`, it started passing. A bit of a head scratcher!

Comment: I ran into this issue and could not figure it out. I wonder how it was working for you all and not on my setup. Was hoping not to test manually, if anyone has ideas that would be great. Is the tap that I am using for elevated button not triggering the validate method somehow?

Comment: @MattR That tells the testing widget to imply all the changes and run all animations e.g. a validation error.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to verify the validation error message from a `TextFormField`, it is not straightforward but possible.

We can use the key of our `TextFormField`:

```dart
TextFormField(
  key: const Key('field_key'),
  // Rest of attributes...
),
```

Then we scope our `find.text()` to find only within the descendants of the `TextFormField` like this:

```dart
final textFormField = find.byKey(const Key('field_key'));
final textFinder = find.text('Email is required');
final validationMessage = find.descendant(of: textFormField, matching: textFinder)
    .first.evaluate().single.widget as Text;
expect(validationMessage.data, 'Email is required');
```

Alternatively, we can be a little bit less strict by just checking that the text exists as a child of the `TextFormField`:

```dart
final textFormField = find.byKey(const Key('field_key'));
final textFinder = find.text('Email is required');
final validationMessageFinder = find.descendant(of: textFormField, matching: textFinder);
expect(validationMessageFinder, findsOneWidget);
```